# Thm IV, Prob IV, Two New Sciences

Tags: geometry, physics, math-history

In Thm. 4, Prop. 4 of Galileo's 'Two New Sciences' (pg. 187, Crew Translation), Galileo says the following: "From a single point $B$ draw the planes $BA$ and $BC$, having the same length but different inclinations; let $AE$ and $CD$ be horizontal lines drawn to meet the perpendicular $BD$; and let $BE$ represent the height of the plane $AB$, and $BD$ the height of $BC$; also let $BI$ be a mean proportional to $BD$ and $BE$; then the ratio of $BD$ to $BI$ is equal to the square root of the ratio of $BD$ to $BE$." (See figure)[figure 5.4, Two New Sciences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Mns.png)

But I don't see how this could be the case. If I use two right triangles, one of height $\frac{1}{2}$ and the other of height $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, I don't get the result Galileo did. Could it be that he erred? Help me clear up my confusion lads

Comment: How $BA$ and $BC$ can be a plane?

Comment: This theorem is saying that if $BD:BI = BI:BE$ then $BI^2:BD^2=BE:BD$, so it must hold for your numbers.

Comment: @Chrystomath Galileo never states that $BD:BI = BI : BE$ is a hypothesis of the theorem.

Comment: @SarGe In this context Galileo is using 'plane' to refer to the hypotenuse of a right triangle.

Comment: @ZacharyCandelaria That's the meaning of "let $BI$ be a mean proportional to $BD$ and $BE$".

Answer (score 1):

As $BI$ is [mean proportional](https://www.quora.com/What-is-mean-proportion) to $BD$ and $BE$.

\begin{array}{l}
\Rightarrow \frac{B D}{B I}=\frac{B I}{B E} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{B D}{B I} \times B D=\frac{B I}{B E} \times B D \\
\Rightarrow \frac{B D^{2}}{B I}=\frac{B I \times B D}{B E} \\
\Rightarrow \quad \frac{B D^{2}}{B I^{2}}=\frac{B D}{B E}
\end{array}

$Q.E.D$